# How can I resolve net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED error while installing Python extension on Vscode in my VM?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions

My corporate IT department said that he has whitelisted the python extension link:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

I was able to download the extension and install the visx file but still get below error:

2024-02-09 10:02:56.671 [error] net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED: Download: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
at c.download (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:83:16609)
at async ie.x (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:102:119397)
at async ie.h (c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:102:117123)

This issue is also creating problems for me to use jupyter in vscode as python infrastructure is not completely installed inside the VsCode.